# How can I increase the Ubuntu partition for dual boot with Vista

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-vista

I have installed Ubuntu as a dual boot on a vista system with a 120GB HDD. Ubuntu needs a bit more room to operate. I have 65% free room on the vista partition but after defragmentation 2 "unmovable" files are located at the end of the partition.
I would like to know how to remove one unmovable file called $bitmap and if it is safe to delete the unmovable swap file "pagefile" from within Ubuntu. If I manage to remove those 2 files I would be able to shrink the vista partition and consequently increase the ubuntu partition.

Comment: 1) [grab a system image](https://www.maketecheasier.com/clone-drives-and-partitions-with-clonezilla/) that you can later restore from if necessary. 2) What have you tried already? Can you not resize the partition in question from the Windows disk manager utility? 3) Was Ubuntu installed on LVM?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer...

No, you don't want to manipulate Vista files from Ubuntu. And no, you don't want to delete these files from Vista either.

## Make good backups first, as these procedures can loose or corrupt data. You've been warned.

To be able to **shrink** your Vista partition, you'll need to turn off **page file** in Vista, reboot, then defrag, then **shrink** the NTFS C: partition, then re-enable the **page file**.

Then boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and use `gparted` to `swapoff`, then manipulate your EXT4 and swap partitions, then `swapon`, to get the increased space for Ubuntu.